# Calculating data and render them after fetching all data from server side; $(window).load() no luck

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a `<s:iterator>` to fetch all data from server side and display them in page:

```
<s:iterator id="lstActividades" value="impDesLst">
    <tr>
        <td><input ng-change="actualizarDias();" type="text" class="form-control" name="produccionForm.minutosL<s:property value="%{actividad.idActividad}" />" id="produccionForm.minutosL<s:property value="%{actividad.idActividad}" />" ng_model="minutosL<s:property value="%{actividad.idActividad}" />" ng-init="minutosL<s:property value="%{actividad.idActividad}" />='<s:property value="%{producciones[0].minutos}" />'" /></td>
```

Note that it has `ng-change=actualizarDias()` which calculate all data in a row and render the result. It works well when the number changes.

However, I want to get the result when the page is loaded for the first time. Now the result field is blank, but if we press F5 or change one number, all result come out correctly.

As I can see, if I want to use jQuery function, they must be defined out of Angular controller, so I tried:

- define `$(window).load(function(){});` out of Angular controller, like this:

  `$(window).load(function(){
      angular.element(document).scope().actualizarDias();
  });`
- define following function inside Angular controller:

  `$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function ($evt) {
          $scope.actualizarDias();
      });//not working`
- define following function also inside Augular controller:

  `setTimeout(function(){
          $scope.$apply(function() {
              $(window).load(function(){
              $scope.actualizarDias();
          });
          });
       });//not working`

To no avail.

My script is in an isolated `jsp` file with following structure:

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
    response.setDateHeader ("Expires", -1); 
%>

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<script type="text/javascript">

angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $modal, $window, $http, ProccessFormService) {
    $scope.function1 = function() {...};

    $scope.function2 = function() {....};

    $scope.actualizarDias() = function() {...};

}
```

Now, how can I load my result when I enter the page for the first time?

My calculation function is:

```
$scope.actualizarDias = function(){
    tabla = document.getElementById('tablaProducciones').children[1];
    $scope.impL="";
    $scope.minutosTotalesL="";
    $scope.minutosTotalesLFormat="";
    for (var i=1; i<tabla.children.length*2; i++){
        if (i%2!=0) {
            var inputL = tabla.childNodes[i].cells[2].children[0].value;
            var inputAct = tabla.childNodes[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
            if($scope.impL=="" || $scope.impL==undefined){
                $scope.impL=inputAct + "-" + inputL;
                } else {
                $scope.impL+=";" + inputAct + "-" + inputL;
                }
            if (!isNaN(inputL) && inputL>0){
                if ($scope.minutosTotalesL=='' || $scope.minutosTotalesL==undefined){
                    $scope.minutosTotalesL=inputL;
                } else {
                    $scope.minutosTotalesL=parseInt($scope.minutosTotalesL) + parseInt(inputL);
                    }
                $scope.minutosTotalesLFormat = $scope.minutosAHoras($scope.minutosTotalesL);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the function in the main body of your controller to make sure it is executed when the controller is created:

```
function MyController() {
    $scope.actualizarDias = function(){
        ...
    }

    $scope.actualizarDias();
}
```

Although as it stands that will probably still fail as you've got a lot of view specific code in your controller which is a really bad idea.  You should look to change the structure of your code so that the data in the table is loaded in to your controller and bind to that rather than having your controller iterating over a table.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it's not working. The thing is, the number of rows in this table is not certain until we have fetched data from server side. Although we can set `ng-model`/`id` as `xxxx + numRow`, we don't know beforehand where it ends. Thus we are not able to bind every input. I will try to fetch the calculation result along with all other data, although it can be harder..

Comment: At last I managed to do calculation at server side and send the result to client and render them, in spite of calculating them in browser. Thanks all.